# Rails layout - css 404 not found for some pages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm super-new to Rails, this is undoubtedly an amateur issue...

I'm working on a simple app to collect user posts, but my layout is not applying to all of my pages - specifically, it is not applying to pages with the /new path because the associated css file cannot be found.  My Rails version is 4.2.5.

Here are my routes:

```
root 'home#home.html.erb'
resources :users
resources :posts
```

I haven't put anything into my controllers yet, but here they are anyway (each in a separate file, of course):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController

   def index
   end

   def new
   end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def index
   end

   def new
   end

end
```

My layout file is the default application.html.erb file in the layouts folder, and it references a stylesheet in the public folder like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

When my root, users index, and posts index pages render, the layout is applied, no problem.  However, when I go to the users/new or posts/new pages, the app attempts to render with the layout but I get a 404 error that the stylesheet is not found.  Inspecting the network for the /new pages, I noticed that the request URL for the stylesheet is http://localhost:3000/users/css/stylesheet.css, while it is http://localhost:3000/css/stylesheet.css for all of the other (working) pages.

Why are the pages with the /new path looking for this resource elsewhere (I presume in the assets folder), and how can I tame them so that all of my pages reference the same css resource?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm super-new to Rails

Welcome!

---

## Do this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :stylesheet %>
```

You will also need to move your `stylesheet.css` into `app/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css`

---

You currently have a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) issue.

When you call `url.com/users`, and are using a *relative* path for your stylesheet, you'll basically get your browser looking for file based on the current directory (IE `users/css/stylesheets`).

Rails uses an [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) to store your assets; you should **not** put them in your `/public` folder.

If you put your stylesheet in your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder (where it's meant to go), Rails will use the [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) helpers. This allows Rails to use the correct path (not a relative one), which will ensure your stylesheet will always be available.

---

As an aside, you'll be better using the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
root 'home#home'         # -> routes go to controller actions, not views
resources :users, :posts # -> you can define multiple resources at once
```

Refs:

- [Using Root](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)
- [Multiple resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time)

Comment: That's great, thank you very much.  I also had to add 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( stylesheet.css )' to config/initialize/assets.rb, but Rails was kind enough to tell me this.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a css or scss file specifically for each controller you have in `app > assets > stylesheets`

or you can create a partial e.g _headerStyle.scss and in the application.scss
import the partial by `@import "headerStyle";` partial is also a good technique to DRY up your code.

a good read regarding assets pipeline -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate the link to the assets pipeline resource.